# How to find out what scheduling algorithm does the OS use

Tags: linux, windows, algorithm, posix, scheduling

Everytime we make a `fork()` call to create a new process , whether the parent process or child process runs first depends on the scheduling algorithm . Is there any command/way to find out what scheduling algorithm your OS uses ???

I wonder if the methods to find out the scheduling algorithm is the same for windows and linux???

Comment: Which one "runs first" is an unimportant implementation detail, and will likely be nondeterministic under some circumstances. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Find out which scheduling algorithm the operating system uses does not always means you can predict which process (parent or child) will run first.

Comment: @leeduhem why is that so ??

Comment: @Computernerd Besides scheduling algorithm, the specific circumstance of your system at the `fork()` moment may also affect which process will run first.

Comment: @Computernerd You understand that the point of `fork()` is for the two processes to run concurrently, right?

Comment: If you want one process to do some particular thing before or after the other process does some other particular thing, you'll need OS-provided interprocess synchronisation primitives like semaphores, locks, named pipes, events, channels or shared memory.